# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal?

Tags: javascript

How to count the number of line breaks in a textarea?

```
<?php
echo "<textarea value=\"\" id=\"text\" maxlength=\"200\" wrap=\"virtual\" onChange=\"test()\"></textarea>
<script>
                            function test()
                            {
                                var text = $('#text').val();   
                                var lines = text.split('\n');//SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
                                var count = lines.length;
                                console.log('+'+count); // Outputs 4
                            }
                            </script>";
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the quotes on `$(\"#text\")`. Since that's JS code, you actually do want quotes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in `\n`. Otherwise, it's interpreted by PHP because it's inside a double-quoted string, so it becomes a literal newline in the Javascript.

```
            var lines = text.split('\\n');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<textarea cols="30" id="countLines"></textarea>

var textarea = document.getElementById("countLines");
var spaces = textarea.getAttribute("cols");

textarea.onmouseout = function() {
   var lines = textarea.value.split("\n");

   for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) 
   {
         if (lines[i].length <= spaces) continue;
         var j = 0;

        var space = spaces;

        while (j++ <= spaces) 
        {
           if (lines[i].charAt(j) === " ") space = j;  
        }
    lines[i + 1] = lines[i].substring(space + 1) + (lines[i + 1] || "");
    lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, space);
  }
    var count = lines.length;
};
```

checkout the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ryog4/gj5c2bkd/1/